# How to initialize vehicles position randomly on the route using OMNET++?

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I want to set randomly vehicles positions on the route. My SUMO files has the same start and end points, but I couldn't find how to set a new coordination.
Is there any ways to do it using OMNET++?

Comment: Please amend your question with the SuMO route file and a more extend description of what you try to achieve.

Comment: I want to distribute vehicles on the road with different positions randomly , this is my files map;rou.xml [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AtidikA1MEF8IIbjXJZFtwCEJfvkM1Mi/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

The [SUMO Wiki Page on "Definition of Vehicles, Vehicle Types, and Routes"](http://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/Definition_of_Vehicles,_Vehicle_Types,_and_Routes) has the following to offer:

> A vehicle may be defined using the following attributes:
>
> - **depart**: (≥0, "triggered", "containerTriggered") The time step at which the vehicle shall enter the network [...]
> - **departLane**: (≥0, "random", "free", "allowed", "best", "first") The lane on which the vehicle shall be inserted [...]
> - **departPos**: ("random", "free", "random_free", "base", "last")   The position at which the vehicle shall enter the net
>     [...]

Seems like you are looking for the **departPos** parameter.

Comment: thank you this is exactly what I'm searching for @Christoph Sommer